# Parsing Amount<Currency> in Corda shell

Tags: corda

I'd like to initiate a flow in Corda (v3.3) shell with

```
flow start IOUIssueFlow state: { newIOUState: { amount: $100 } }
```

(the rest of the flow parameters are cut for brevity.)

however the parsing fails with

> No matching constructor found:
>   - [com.template.IOUState]: Could not parse as a command: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.template.IOUState] value failed for JSON
>   property amount due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator
>   parameter amount which is a non-nullable type  at [Source: UNKNOWN;
>   line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain:
>   com.template.IOUState["amount"])

`IOUIssueFlow`'s constructor has a single `state` parameter of type `IOUState`. `IOUState`'s constructor starts with:

```
data class IOUState(val amount: Amount<Currency>,
                    val lender : Party,
                    val borrower: Party,
                    val paid : Amount<Currency> = Amount(0, amount.token),
                    override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()): LinearState {...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and it looks like bug in jackson. I wasn't able to construct an object as parameter in Corda shell, so I had to fallback to providing all necessary "simple" parameters as input of the Flow and constructing the object inside it.

Comment: Can you please share  your command

I enter the command `flow start IOUIssueFlow$InitiatorFlow state: {amount: $1000, lender: "O=Supplier Service,OU=coffeebeans,L=Sydney,C=AU", borrower: "O=Consumer Service,OU=coffeebeans,L=Sydney,C=AU"}` but it keep failing with
`No matching constructor found:
- [arg0: yyy.state.IOUState]: missing parameter arg0`

I'm using java not kotlin